# AngularJSのディレクティブで動的に作成したタグでバインドする方法

Tags: angularjs

AngularJSについて質問です。

ディレクティブを使用して新しいDIVタグを追加し、そのDIVタグで値のバインドを行いたいのですがうまくいきません。
例えば

sample.html

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList">
    <user-directive user="user">
</div>
```

sample.js

```
app.module.directive("userDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {"user" : "&"},
        link : function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var user = $scope.user();
            var tag = $("<div>名前：{{user.name}} ({{user.age}})</div>");
            $element.append(tag);
        }
    }
});
```

といったコードの場合、

```
名前：{{user.name}} ({{user.age}})
```

の部分でバインドしてほしいのですが、実際には{{や}}も含めてそのまま画面に表示されてしまいます。
そもそもこういった使い方が間違っているのかもしれませんが、もし良い方法がありましたらご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

思いつく方法としては、

1.`template`を利用して置き換える。
2.`$compile`を利用して手動で反映させる。

でしょうか。

2.については、「AngularJSリファレンス」という本に記載されています。
また下記の内容も参考になるかと思います。

[Does dynamically adding ng-bind directive not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430333/does-dynamically-adding-ng-bind-directive-not-work)

1.

```
app.module.directive("userDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        template: "<div>名前：{{user.name}} ({{user.age}})</div>"
    };
});
```

2.

```
app.module.directive("userDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {"user" : "="},
        link : function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var elem = angular.element("<div>名前：{{user.name}} ({{user.age}})</div>");
            $element.append($compile(elem)($scope));
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

oTak さん
回答ありがとうございます！ 2の方法で解決しました。

```
app.module.directive("userDirective", ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {"user" : "="},
        link : function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var tag = $("<div>名前：{{user.name}} ({{user.age}})</div>");
            $element.append($compile(tag)($scope));
        }
    }
}]);
```

実は変数名の user という名前がディレクティブの呼び出し元によって違うことがあるので(中身は同じなのですが)、templateだとその名前が固定になってしまうと思ったので2の方法を採用することにしました。

$compile の存在を知らなかったので勉強になりました。どうもありがとうございます。